# Cannot print char array from stdin in c

Tags: c, char

I am trying to read in from stdin and then print each char from each string but it will not print anything for some reason...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

  int i;
  char string[10];
  while (fgets(string,10,stdin)!=NULL){
    for(i=0;i<strlen(string);i++);{
      printf("%c",string[i]);
    }
    strcpy(string,"");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried closing the input stream?  (eg, redirect from a file, or try ctrl-D when entering text interactively)

Comment: [`fflush(stdout);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)

Comment: check you aren't reading a Windows text file in *nix either

Comment: It's just an extraneous semicolon, so this question should be closed for containing a typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extraneous semicolon.

Try this:

```
...
for(i=0;i<strlen(string);i++){
    for...
```

Notice the lack of a ";" before the body of the loop.

The body of the loop in your code is empty because it's just a semicolon.
The part that you intend as the body of the loop is only executed once afterwards. During that one execution you're just printing the null character at the end of string.